# Why does my instance of Random behave incorrectly?

Tags: haskell

I have the following source

```
-- Quantity.hs
import System.Random

data Quantity = Quantity Integer deriving (Show)

instance Random Quantity where
    randomR (Quantity lo, Quantity hi) g =
        let rand = randomR (lo, hi) g
            (r, g) = rand
        in (Quantity r, g)
    random g =
        let rand = random g
            (r, g) = rand
        in (Quantity r, g)
```

When I do `ghci Quantity.hs` and then

```
let g = mkStdGen 0
let (r, g1) = random g :: (Quantity, StdGen)
r
```

the output of last step is

```
Quantity <no newline>
```

and the computation apparently hangs, but the CPU doesn't do anything (confirmed via System Monitor).

At the same time

```
let (r, g1) = random g :: (Integer, StdGen)
Quantity r
```

works and outputs

```
Quantity 2092838931
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Haskell, the order of the definitions of a `let` expression does not matter. That is, the expression

```
let x = 1
    y = x + 1
in
y
```

evaluates to `2` as well as the following expression.

```
let y = x + 1
    x = 1
in
y
```

As a consequence, on the right-hand side of a definition all other definitions are visible and hide variables with the same name. That is, in your definition

```
random g =
  let rand = random g
      (r, g) = rand
  in (Quantity r, g)
```

the `g` defined in the second definition of the `let` hides the argument of `random`. Therefore, the definition of `g` is recursive and its evaluation does not terminate.